# Removing number of the page of a list of symbols

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, glossaries

I'm trying to make a list of symbols for my thesis using the package 'glossaries-extra'. However, the first page of the list of symbols comes with its number page in the bottom part and I want to remove it, to have a plain style page. How do I make it?

I'm basically using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,english,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Electric field}]{E}{$\textbf{E}$}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,nonumberlist,title={List of Symbols}]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\input{chapter 0 - Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try writing `thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: Your code produces the result you wanted. (The first  `\thispagestyle{empty}`  is superfluous). I used `\chapter*{chapter 0 - Introduction}` so the style changes to `plain`.